# A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later. Ajax call

Tags: magento2.4, ajax, redirect, admin-controller, redirection

I have a problem here. I use Ajax call to send data to controller.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button'
], function($, button){
    'use strict';

    return button.extend({
        defaults: {
            elementTmpl: 'ui/form/element/button',
            imports: {
                data: '${ $.provider }:data'
            }
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            console.log('init');
        },
        sendData: function () {
            console.log('ok');
            let id = this.data.id,
                pattern = $('[name="pattern"]').val(),
                addQty = $('[name="add_qty"]').val(),
                addValue = $('[name="add_value"]').val(),
                expiry = $('[name="expiry"]').val(),
                sendData = {
                    'id': id,
                    'pattern': pattern,
                    'add_qty': addQty,
                    'add_value': addValue,
                    'expiry': expiry,
                },
                generateUrl = this.data.generate_url;

            console.log(sendData);
            console.log(generateUrl);
            console.log(id);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: generateUrl,
                data: sendData,
                dataType: 'json',
                encode: true,
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Then my controller do its job.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Bss\GiftCard\Controller\Adminhtml\GiftCode;

use Bss\GiftCard\Api\GiftCodeRepositoryInterface;
use Bss\GiftCard\Model\GiftCodeFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

/**
 * Class Save saves form
 */
class Generate extends Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var GiftCodeFactory
     */
    protected $giftCodeFactory;

    /**
     * @var GiftCodeRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $giftCodeRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param GiftCodeFactory $giftCodeFactory
     * @param GiftCodeRepositoryInterface $giftCodeRepositoryInterface
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context                             $context,
        RequestInterface                    $request,
        GiftCodeFactory              $giftCodeFactory,
        GiftCodeRepositoryInterface  $giftCodeRepositoryInterface,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->giftCodeFactory = $giftCodeFactory;
        $this->giftCodeRepositoryInterface = $giftCodeRepositoryInterface;
    }

    private function generateCode($pattern) {
        do {
            $code = $pattern;
            while (($pos = strpos($code, "{D}"))) {
                $code = substr_replace($code, chr(rand(48, 57)), $pos, 3);
            }
            while (($pos = strpos($code, "{L}"))) {
                $code = substr_replace($code, chr(rand(65, 90)), $pos, 3);
            }
        }
        while ($this->giftCodeRepositoryInterface->checkExisted($code));
        return $code;
    }

    /**
     * Generate code
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        try {
            $data = $this->request->getParams();
            if (!isset($data['id'])) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("Save Gift Code Pattern first!");
                $resultRedirect->setPath('bss/giftcodepattern/form');
            } else {
                $quantity = (int)$data['add_qty'];
                for ($i = 0; $i < $quantity; $i++) {
                    $resultData = [
                        'pattern_id' => $data['id'],
                        'code' => $this->generateCode($data['pattern']),
                        'status' => \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable::ENABLE_VALUE,
                        'current' => $data['add_value'],
                        'initial' => $data['add_value'],
                        'order' => null,
                        'expiry' => $data['expiry'],
                        'sender_name' => null,
                        'sender_email' => null,
                        'recipient_name' => null,
                        'recipient_email' => null,
                        'message' => null,
                    ];
                    $model = $this->giftCodeFactory->create();
                    $model->addData($resultData);
                    $this->giftCodeRepositoryInterface->save($model);
                }
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__(
                    'Save Successfully!'
                ));
                $resultRedirect->setPath('bss/giftcodepattern/form', ['id' => $data['id']]);
            }
            return $resultRedirect;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__(
                'There was an error, please try again!'
            ));
            $resultRedirect->setPath('bss/giftcodepattern/index');
        }
        $resultRedirect->setPath('bss/giftcodepattern/index');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Then redirect. But I got a problem. My controller generate code and save to database as I expected but NOT redirect.
"A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later."
[image]
[image]
I could'nt find a solution. I think its caused by ajax call. Could u help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot redirect page using Ajax.

From [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/asp/asp_ajax_intro.asp):

> AJAX is a technique for creating fast and dynamic web pages.
>
> AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging small amounts of data with the server behind the scenes. This means that it is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page.

You need to redirect using : https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/12004981

Comment: Oh, that mean i cant use $resultRedirect. if i want redirect, i must write it in js file?

Comment: @NghiaHoangTrong you can use this Ajax code where success and error of your call. you can redirect the page in the success function. Also, you send the return URL from Ajax using json.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63205687/how-to-call-php-function-when-ajax-query-success